# How to apply role for KPIs on SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a problem with applying roles for KPIs on SSAS Tabular Model, I created some KPIs but I cant set any roles for them so everyone can see them when they connect to the model using excel even apply "Hide From Client Tools" option. How can I manage this?

[image]

[image]